# How are hard links counted in UNIX?

Tags: hard-link, ln

When we create a directory in UNIX it has 2 hard links: `.` and `..`.
One to itself and another one to its parent directory.

As I read the `.` increases counter of the directory, and the `..` increases hard links counter of parent directory.

So only `.` is counted in the directory, but there are still 2 hard links when I do `ls -l`.
What is the second one?
Can someone tell me how hard links are counted in directories?
Imagine, we have this hierachy:

```
parent    - 4 hard links
.
. child_1 - 2 hard links
.
. child_2 - 2 hard links
```

Answer (score 3):

`child1` has two links because of the `child1` entry in the parent and the `.` entry in `child1`.

Note that `parent` in the described constellation usually has **four** links, not 3 because it is the child of some other parent (unless it's the root dir):

```
$ find parent | xargs stat -c "%h %n"  # %h=link count, %n=name
4 parent
2 parent/child2
2 parent/child1
```

Comment: On the _extN_ filesystems even `/` has `..`. It's just that it points to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. That's what I got asking my lecturer:

The `.` increments by 1 the count for the directory itself.
The `..` increments by 1 the count of the parent directory.
New child directories have 2 hard-links because the name of the directory is a hard-link as well linking to this directory.

Comment: I'd say this is pretty similar to what my answer describes.

Comment: Here a little difference that may be important. `child1` has 2 hard links because tha name: `child1` is a hard link too. Together with the `.` hard link it makes 2 hard-links totally.